# Mockery and method_exists

Tags: php, mocking, phpunit, mockery

I need to mock an existence of a method of a mocked class with Mockery, but when I use method_exists to check I have a false result:

```
$mock = m::mock('ClassA')->makePartial();
$mock->shouldReceive('getMethod')->andReturn('A');
var_dump(method_exists($mock, 'getMethod'));
```

Result:

```
bool(false)
```

How to make it works?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

getMethod must not exist in ClassA for method_exists to fail.

When mocking an existing class, method_exists will return true for any method that actually exists in that class.

When the method does not exist, since shouldReceive will not actually define a method but will use overloading (`__call`), it will still return false.

Comment: Indeed. So, how to check a mocked method existence?

Comment: Why would you be mocking a method that doesn't exist?

Comment: The method exists but the class is a stub.

Comment: Seems like you should add that method to the stub then.  You could use is_callable but that will return true on anything for a mock.

Comment: Yes. is_callable always return true.

Comment: Solved! Like you said, I created and import the class to use an existing class and not a stub. And the method_exists works because the class exists too.

Answer (score -1):

You could override the `method_exists` function for the namespace of the class under test ...

The below code goes into the test case file...

```
// someTest.php

namespace App\Class\Under\Test\Namespace;

function method_exists($object, $method_name) {

    if ($method_name == 'getMethod') {
        return true;
    }
    return \method_exists($object, $method_name);
};
```